# JQuery (or non-flash) Drop and bounce effect for image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Before I start; i'm new here and have very little experience with JQuery and coding in general so be nice :)

Basically, I am building a launch page for a series of websites (mix of Joomla and Wordpress). The launch page is the www.domain.co.uk/ home directory and then the websites are subdomains with www.site.domain.co.uk/. I am trying to go with a clean "look" for this page and basically would like an effect to be applied to a PNG logo.

If you have ever used Apple Keynote you may know the "Drop" object build effect that basically simulates an image dropping and bouncing slightly like a ball, then stop. My idea is for the logo to have this effect (possibly JQuery so itll work on mobile devices) and then once it is clicked to load a shadowbox. I have got as far as adding the shadowbox but no drop effect! I'm half-way there!

I'd like the logo to drop about half way down a 750x1000px page and bounce appropriately!

I have been searching for this for a long time with no luck on how to do it. The furthest I got is knowing that I may have to mix two jquery UI effects together. Where do I even start I ask myself!

I was wondering if anyone had achieved this in the past and could maybe try build or show me some basic code that I could tweak and add the subject logo to?

I really look forward to hearing from you all! Thanks for reading :)

Comment: jQueryUI's [easeOutBounce](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) easing.

Answer (score 0):

set up an animation loop using the setInterval function

use CSS positioning and an easing function to regulate the movement.  Google Grant Skinner - if memory serves me he's got a site with some great easy to use equations.  Shouldn't be hard to translate into javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the great [jQuery Easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). Set the demo options to easeOutBounce and def to get an idea of the effects.